# Google Maps default zoom level

Tags: google-maps

I created a public map using my Google Map. I want to set a default zoom level, but it is not saved. Is this possible?
Also, is it possible to change the list of place markers?

Comment: I am assuming you are using the Google Maps API, right?... If yes, what behaviour are you trying to accomplish re the default zoom level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing is saved by a web page. HTML browsing is stateless. If you want to save some information you will need to use similar trick as any other web applications. E.g. putting it in cookie and the setting the zoom level using the information in the cookie when you initial the page.

Comment: I am actually using Google Maps Maker.

This is an example of what I am trying to do.

http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?source=embed&hl=en&geocode=&ie=UTF8&msa=0&msid=112492115201367239282.0004609e0fcc239c4f792&ll=46.81084,-71.217113&spn=0.02056,0.038624&z=15

Comment: Now I understand this bit more. In the link that you've embedded, its last parameter is z=nn. You can assign it a different number to set different default zoom level. In general, I usually pan and zoom the map to a desired view. Then click link button to obtain an URL that open map into the same view.

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to rearrange the order of the list of Place markers on the left?

Comment: Yes. Under Click My Maps | Edit. You can then rearrange order of items by drag and drop.

Answer (score 4):

the reference map that you supply (quebec summer festival) is called by the URL: http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?source=embed&hl=en&geocode=&ie=UTF8&msa=0&msid=112492115201367239282.0004609e0fcc239c4f792&ll=46.81084,-71.217113&spn=0.02056,0.038624&z=15

notice that the last parameter "&z=15" defines the zoom level (in the embed map code, "&z=15" becomes "& a m p ; z = 1 5" [remove spaces between letters]).  if you change this you can increase or decrease the zoom level.  if you suppress the zoom level, googlemaps will automatically calculate a zoom level when displaying said map.  NORMALLY this leaves some of your map outside the frame.

so, just by supplying the URL with the desired zoomlevel you have solved your problem.  this works very well with static maps.  if you have a dynamically generated map (from a database, for example), the fastest solution is to put 2 markers (top left and bottom right corners) slightly outside your boundary box.  this will force automatic zoom in the desired amount (hopefully).

Answer (score 2):

Not using API just made a map points using my GMail account and made it public, like the following site: 
http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?source=embed&hl=en&geocode=&ie=UTF8&msa=0&msid=112492115201367239282.0004609e0fcc239c4f792&ll=46.81084,-71.217113&spn=0.02056,0.038624&z=15

Comment: that's a great solution, because it brings an added bonus: you do not use your 25K/month API access quota (you accept these terms when you generated your api key).

check this out if you want to generate static kml maps on the fly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8566064/creating-a-kml-file-from-a-mysql-database-with-php/8985488#8985488