# Creating a kml file from a mysql database with php

Tags: php, mysql, kml

I hope there is a php genius here somewhere who can help me with this.  I have a database table called **baeir**, it has the following fields:

**b_id  (primary key)

b_name 

hrepparid (does not need to be displayed)

stjarna (does not need to be displayed)

lat

lng

comments**



The table contains a name of a farm (b_name), its geographical coordinates (lat, lng) and comments - if there are any.

What I need is to get this data into a kml file.  I have tried to go through the tutorial on google's webpage and I got it to work BUT once I try to edit, it goes to h***.  As far as I can understand, a kml file is basically an xml file but unfortunately my php skills are not advanced enough to handle this.

I hope someone can help :-))

This is the code I have from google, and it looks a bit too...detailed for my liking.  Any ideas how to simplify the code so that I can get my variables into it and nothing else?

```
<?php
require('phpsqlajax_dbinfo.php');

// Opens a connection to a MySQL server.

$connection = mysql_connect ($server, $username, $password);

if (!$connection) 
{
  die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}
// Sets the active MySQL database.
$db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection);

if (!$db_selected) 
{
  die('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error());
}

// Selects all the rows in the markers table.
$query = 'SELECT * FROM markers WHERE 1';
$result = mysql_query($query);

if (!$result) 
{
  die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

// Creates the Document.
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');


// Creates the root KML element and appends it to the root document.
$node = $dom->createElementNS('http://earth.google.com/kml/2.1', 'kml');
$parNode = $dom->appendChild($node);

// Creates a KML Document element and append it to the KML element.
$dnode = $dom->createElement('Document');
$docNode = $parNode->appendChild($dnode);


// Creates the two Style elements, one for restaurant and one for bar, and append the elements to the Document element.
$restStyleNode = $dom->createElement('Style');
$restStyleNode->setAttribute('id', 'restaurantStyle');
$restIconstyleNode = $dom->createElement('IconStyle');
$restIconstyleNode->setAttribute('id', 'restaurantIcon');
$restIconNode = $dom->createElement('Icon');
$restHref = $dom->createElement('href', 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pal2/icon63.png');
$restIconNode->appendChild($restHref);
$restIconstyleNode->appendChild($restIconNode);
$restStyleNode->appendChild($restIconstyleNode);
$docNode->appendChild($restStyleNode);

$barStyleNode = $dom->createElement('Style');
$barStyleNode->setAttribute('id', 'barStyle');
$barIconstyleNode = $dom->createElement('IconStyle');
$barIconstyleNode->setAttribute('id', 'barIcon');
$barIconNode = $dom->createElement('Icon');
$barHref = $dom->createElement('href', 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pal2/icon27.png');
$barIconNode->appendChild($barHref);
$barIconstyleNode->appendChild($barIconNode);
$barStyleNode->appendChild($barIconstyleNode);
$docNode->appendChild($barStyleNode);

// Iterates through the MySQL results, creating one Placemark for each row.
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
  // Creates a Placemark and append it to the Document.

  $node = $dom->createElement('Placemark');
  $placeNode = $docNode->appendChild($node);

  // Creates an id attribute and assign it the value of id column.
  $placeNode->setAttribute('id', 'placemark' . $row['id']);

  // Create name, and description elements and assigns them the values of the name and address columns from the results.
  $nameNode = $dom->createElement('name',htmlentities($row['name']));
  $placeNode->appendChild($nameNode);
  $descNode = $dom->createElement('description', $row['address']);
  $placeNode->appendChild($descNode);
  $styleUrl = $dom->createElement('styleUrl', '#' . $row['type'] . 'Style');
  $placeNode->appendChild($styleUrl);

  // Creates a Point element.
  $pointNode = $dom->createElement('Point');
  $placeNode->appendChild($pointNode);

  // Creates a coordinates element and gives it the value of the lng and lat columns from the results.
  $coorStr = $row['lng'] . ','  . $row['lat'];
  $coorNode = $dom->createElement('coordinates', $coorStr);
  $pointNode->appendChild($coorNode);
}


$kmlOutput = $dom->saveXML();
while (@ob_end_clean());
header('content-type:text/xml;');
echo $kmlOutput;

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as mentioned above, the following Google Maps tutorial answers your question ALMOST completely: http://code.google.com/apis/kml/articles/phpmysqlkml.html

unfortunately, it does not propose code for polygon parsing (which you will need, if you are managing farm areas display), but you can adapt the LinesString parsing method and achieve it.  beware of properly embedding the outerBoundaryIs tag in the Polygon tag AND remember that you must duplicate the starting point for the polygon to be drawn correctly.

```
    $lineNode = $dom->createElement('Polygon');
$placeNode = $placeNode->appendChild($lineNode);
$exnode = $dom->createElement('extrude', '1');
$lineNode->appendChild($exnode);
$almodenode =$dom->createElement(altitudeMode,'relativeToGround');
$lineNode->appendChild($almodenode);
$outerboundnode = $dom->createElement('outerBoundaryIs');
$placeNode = $placeNode->appendChild($outerboundnode);
$ringnode =$dom->createElement('LinearRing');
$placeNode = $placeNode->appendChild($ringnode);
    // optional styletag colors the polygon
//$stylenode =$dom->createElement(styleUrl,'#transYellowPoly');
//$lineNode->appendChild($stylenode);

//Create a coordinates element and give it the value of the lng and lat columns from the results
//$coorNode = $dom->createElement('coordinates',$row['coordinates']);
$coorNode = $dom->createElement('coordinates',$coordinates);
$placeNode = $placeNode->appendChild($coorNode);
```

Comment: do not forget that the GOOGLEMAPS API IS NOT FREE, before you go and invest your time developing an application that uses it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<?php
require('phpsqlajax_dbinfo.php');
 function xmlEntities($str) 
{ 
    $xml = array('&#34;','&#38;','&#38;','&#60;','&#62;','&#160;','&#161;','&#162;','&#163;','&#164;','&#165;','&#166;','&#167;','&#168;','&#169;','&#170;','&#171;','&#172;','&#173;','&#174;','&#175;','&#176;','&#177;','&#178;','&#179;','&#180;','&#181;','&#182;','&#183;','&#184;','&#185;','&#186;','&#187;','&#188;','&#189;','&#190;','&#191;','&#192;','&#193;','&#194;','&#195;','&#196;','&#197;','&#198;','&#199;','&#200;','&#201;','&#202;','&#203;','&#204;','&#205;','&#206;','&#207;','&#208;','&#209;','&#210;','&#211;','&#212;','&#213;','&#214;','&#215;','&#216;','&#217;','&#218;','&#219;','&#220;','&#221;','&#222;','&#223;','&#224;','&#225;','&#226;','&#227;','&#228;','&#229;','&#230;','&#231;','&#232;','&#233;','&#234;','&#235;','&#236;','&#237;','&#238;','&#239;','&#240;','&#241;','&#242;','&#243;','&#244;','&#245;','&#246;','&#247;','&#248;','&#249;','&#250;','&#251;','&#252;','&#253;','&#254;','&#255;');
    $html = array('&quot;','&amp;','&amp;','&lt;','&gt;','&nbsp;','&iexcl;','&cent;','&pound;','&curren;','&yen;','&brvbar;','&sect;','&uml;','&copy;','&ordf;','&laquo;','&not;','&shy;','&reg;','&macr;','&deg;','&plusmn;','&sup2;','&sup3;','&acute;','&micro;','&para;','&middot;','&cedil;','&sup1;','&ordm;','&raquo;','&frac14;','&frac12;','&frac34;','&iquest;','&Agrave;','&Aacute;','&Acirc;','&Atilde;','&Auml;','&Aring;','&AElig;','&Ccedil;','&Egrave;','&Eacute;','&Ecirc;','&Euml;','&Igrave;','&Iacute;','&Icirc;','&Iuml;','&ETH;','&Ntilde;','&Ograve;','&Oacute;','&Ocirc;','&Otilde;','&Ouml;','&times;','&Oslash;','&Ugrave;','&Uacute;','&Ucirc;','&Uuml;','&Yacute;','&THORN;','&szlig;','&agrave;','&aacute;','&acirc;','&atilde;','&auml;','&aring;','&aelig;','&ccedil;','&egrave;','&eacute;','&ecirc;','&euml;','&igrave;','&iacute;','&icirc;','&iuml;','&eth;','&ntilde;','&ograve;','&oacute;','&ocirc;','&otilde;','&ouml;','&divide;','&oslash;','&ugrave;','&uacute;','&ucirc;','&uuml;','&yacute;','&thorn;','&yuml;');
    $str = str_replace($html,$xml,$str); 
    $str = str_ireplace($html,$xml,$str); 
    return $str; 
} 

// Opens a connection to a MySQL server.

$connection = mysql_connect ($server, $username, $password);

if (!$connection) 
{
  die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}
// Sets the active MySQL database.
$db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection);

if (!$db_selected) 
{
  die('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error());
}

// Selects all the rows in the markers table.
$query = 'SELECT * FROM baeir WHERE 1';
$result = mysql_query($query);

if (!$result) 
{
  die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

// Creates the Document.
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');


// Creates the root KML element and appends it to the root document.
$node = $dom->createElementNS('http://earth.google.com/kml/2.1', 'kml');
$parNode = $dom->appendChild($node);

// Creates a KML Document element and append it to the KML element.
$dnode = $dom->createElement('Document');
$docNode = $parNode->appendChild($dnode);


// Creates the two Style elements, one for restaurant and one for bar, and append the elements to the Document element.
$restStyleNode = $dom->createElement('Style');
$restStyleNode->setAttribute('id', 'restaurantStyle');
$restIconstyleNode = $dom->createElement('IconStyle');
$restIconstyleNode->setAttribute('id', 'restaurantIcon');
$restIconNode = $dom->createElement('Icon');
$restHref = $dom->createElement('href', 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pal2/icon63.png');
$restIconNode->appendChild($restHref);
$restIconstyleNode->appendChild($restIconNode);
$restStyleNode->appendChild($restIconstyleNode);
$docNode->appendChild($restStyleNode);

$barStyleNode = $dom->createElement('Style');
$barStyleNode->setAttribute('id', 'barStyle');
$barIconstyleNode = $dom->createElement('IconStyle');
$barIconstyleNode->setAttribute('id', 'barIcon');
$barIconNode = $dom->createElement('Icon');
$barHref = $dom->createElement('href', 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pal2/icon27.png');
$barIconNode->appendChild($barHref);
$barIconstyleNode->appendChild($barIconNode);
$barStyleNode->appendChild($barIconstyleNode);
$docNode->appendChild($barStyleNode);

// Iterates through the MySQL results, creating one Placemark for each row.
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
  // Creates a Placemark and append it to the Document.

  $node = $dom->createElement('Placemark');
  $placeNode = $docNode->appendChild($node);

  // Creates an id attribute and assign it the value of id column.
  $placeNode->setAttribute('id', 'placemark' . $row['b_id ']);

  // Create name, and description elements and assigns them the values of the name and address columns from the results.
  $nameNode = $dom->createElement('name',xmlEntities(htmlentities($row['b_name'])));
  $placeNode->appendChild($nameNode);
  $descNode = $dom->createElement('description', $row['comments']);
  $placeNode->appendChild($descNode);
  //$styleUrl = $dom->createElement('styleUrl', '#' . $row['type'] . 'Style');
  //$placeNode->appendChild($styleUrl);

  // Creates a Point element.
  $pointNode = $dom->createElement('Point');
  $placeNode->appendChild($pointNode);

  // Creates a coordinates element and gives it the value of the lng and lat columns from the results.
  $coorStr = $row['lng'] . ','  . $row['lat'];
  $coorNode = $dom->createElement('coordinates', $coorStr);
  $pointNode->appendChild($coorNode);
}


$kmlOutput = $dom->saveXML();
while (@ob_end_clean());
header('content-type:text/xml;');
echo $kmlOutput;

?>
```

Comment: This page contains the following errors:

error on line 2 at column 292: Entity 'Aacute' not defined

Comment: I remove htmlentities, please try again.

Comment: Sorry I still get an error:
This page contains the following errors:
error on line 2 at column 284: Encoding error

Comment: see it here: hafdal.dk/kml/phpsql_genkml_new1.php

Comment: Ok so those entities are causing problems here, and XML does not support all the HTML entities. Please try again, I added a function to convert html entities to XML entities

Comment: you are a GENIOUS!!! It works now!!!  Thanks so much for taking the time to help me!!!!

Comment: No hang on, the description tag seems to be off.  You can see it here: http://www.hafdal.dk/kml/phpsql_genkml_new1.php  The opening tag for description seems to be missing?

Comment: No thats XML, there is no content in the description tag, so it auto-closes it with `/>` instead of showing `<description></description>`
Check the source of the xml, you'll see it.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean - is it enough to change the variable name in this line:  `code` $descNode = $dom->createElement('description', $row['comments']);`code`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6048/discussion-between-saratis-and-user1088537)

Answer (score 1):

kml has nothing to do with your php. Your kml file is basically an xml file which is specifically used in google earth ang google map applications. Your Kml file needs to pass a validity test in order for you to use it. You can use the following link to validate your kml file. [Kml validator](http://kmlvalidator.com/). Your kml file will contain the predefined tags like `point` `coordinate` `description` so that it can be parsed. If you want to take a look as to how the kml file looks like, here you go

[Sample Kml File](http://www.searcharoo.net/SearchKml/newyork.kml)

Needless to say your KML should contain the info in the proper tags and then you need to parse it. e-g lat and lng can go in to the coordinate tag. description tag  can hold your text description, say comment.

Comment: ok I may have formulated this wrong, but what I need is a php file to generate the kml file from mysql database...

I know kml has nothing to do directly with php but I also know that you can generate a kml file with php and that is what I need.

Comment: unfortunately i am not  a php guy, but I think this link should help you, if you haven't already seen this:
http://code.google.com/apis/kml/articles/phpmysqlkml.html

Comment: thanks refhat, I have tried that, but as soon as I edited it, I couldnt get this to work.

Comment: could you report that errors that you may have. I am just saying coz kml is very strict and use my kmlvalidator to validate.